# apache not serving static content correctly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have been working on my own mvc framework to further my web app learning, but am having trouble serving static resources. I am trying to have a single entry point into the application, aka a front controller, so in my project / I have an .htaccess file that redirects all requests to the app/ folder where another .htaccess passes the request uri to index.php (in app/) who delegates the request to the appropriate controllers.

However, when I try to serve up static content, such as javascripts or cascading style sheets, I still get redirected through app/index.php. I am also getting "favicon.ico does not exist in /var/www" errors in /var/log/apache2/errors.log (maybe because of symlink to ~/www?). I do not expect to because of the following .htaccess file in the root directory of my project root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Suppress the "www." at the beginning of URLs
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # The same content should never be available under two different URLs - especially not with and
  # without "www." at the beginning, since this can cause SEO problems (duplicate content).
  # That's why you should choose one of the alternatives and redirect the other one.
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Route static resources to respective files
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond public/$0 -f
  RewriteRule ^.+\.(jpg|gif|png|ico|css|js)$ /public/$0 [L]

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Redirect all other requests to the app folder
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  RewriteRule   ^$    app/   [L]
  RewriteRule   (.*)  app/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and here is the .htaccess in my app/ folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # ensure request is not path to filename or directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # redirect all requests to index.php?url=PATHNAME
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Why can't I serve static content correctly? This would make sense to me if I wasn't trying to sent all static requests to public/, which is where my css, jpg, png, js, etc files reside. But I have a RewriteCond rule in there to send the requests for such files to the public dir... Confusing?

Comment: I've tried removing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` since that filters all files, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, from what I understood, that your project structure is the following:

```
/
/.htaccess
/app/.htaccess
/app/index.php
/public/static.js (for example)
```

Here is what I come up with, hoping it'll solve your problem:
the .htaccess in the root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^public/.+\.(jpg|gif|png|ico|css|js)$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the .htaccess in the app folder is unchanged.

Every request starting with public and being a file with the listed extensions won't be redirected which is done with the dash character.
The last rule allows to redirect a request to the app/index.php file.

I think the resulting behaviour is the expected one:

- static files in the public directory are not redirected,
- files with another extension in the public directory will be
  redirected to app/index.php (maybe for some error treatment),
- requests not starting with public will be redirected to
  app/index.php.

Comment: yes, this is pretty much spot on in terms of my directory structure and what i'm trying to accomplish. thank you! i'll test it out in a few and post the results.

Comment: still doesn't work. When I direct link to the files, I am served the index page (as it is my only action so far) instead of the file. Maybe it should be a RewriteCond <is a file>, RewriteCond <matches these extensions>, RewriteRule <to the public folder>. This might also get rid of the "No favicon.ico in /var/www" message in the apache2 errors.log...

Comment: It's strange because I tested what I posted. Maybe the problem is somewhere else in the Apache config or in your vhost if you use one.

Comment: I think Zend Framework has one of the best approaches concerning the project structure if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: ill keep checking, thanks. ill accept this and hopefully will be able to get it working like you did.