# Codeigniter routes not working when /css or /js in the url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have set a route as

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'category/view/$1';
```

It works every time except when the URL contains mysite.com/css or mysite.com/js.

I want to have URL like `mysite.com/css`, what should I do ??

Thank You.

Comment: make sure you have set your base url on config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htaccess rule so you'll try

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 ReWriteEngine On
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|assets|robots\.txt)
 ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

You probably wanna just remove the extension so this part will do it

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume those are URLs to static files, not dynamically generated Javascript or CSS files. This means that those URLs never need to hit Codeigniter at all. I don't know which web server you are using, but most, if not all, can be configured to route those URLs to a static folder and never touch your PHP engine. Saves you resources as well.

Here is a link on how to do it in Nginx: [Serving Static Content - Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/)

Also for Apache it is answered here: [Apache not serving static content correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7692873)