# CodeIgniter - Controllers not working, only loading index page with plain text

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been trying to find some other solutions online but none yet has worked as I need it to.

I'm working on a CodeIgniter project but, at some point I suppose I have edited something I should not. Now, when I try to call localhost/projectname/controller/function it does ALWAYS (no matter which controller, even if the welcome controller) it will load my index.php file, which is on the root folder of codeigniter (not Views), without any images or css whatsoever, just plain text.

My config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = http://localhost:8080/projectname';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

My routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route[LOGIN_PAGE] = 'examples/login';
```

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I've trying to install [community-auth](https://community-auth.com) and now have been caught with the error, as previously I was just working on the index page design and only now have been trying to access other functions.

I'm using NetBeans 8.2 and XAMPP v3.2.4

This is the index page:
[image: This is the index page]

This is what I get while trying the access controllers/function this is the page loaded:
[image: This is what I get while trying the access controllers/function this is the page loaded]

Any help? Any other information I should provide?

Comment: Maybe you deleted your `.htaccess` file...which CodeIgniter version are you using? It shoould look something like https://gist.github.com/keithmorris/3023560

Comment: It seems that your routes are working, but it's not loading the css and images....take a look at the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683211/apache-not-serving-static-content-correctly/7692873#7692873

Comment: Very first thing to do without thinking (in time) is to view your html source via your browser and Look at the links for you css and images etc. It's a path thing. What do you see?

Comment: Hackerman, I'm using CodeIgniter version 3.1.11.

Comment: Now, I've got the original files from CodeIgniter, just checked that I changed the index.php from the root directory to my own index.php that I was developing before changing to CodeIgniter framework. So here's where I found my error. I put back the original files from codeigniter, merged my own files properly this time, and now it's working. It was while looking for the .htaccess though, so thanks Hackerman!

Comment: add ' before http in your `$config['base_url']`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **$route[LOGIN_PAGE] = 'examples/login';** from routes

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
 $route['404_override'] = '';
 $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once load the page and share the browser inpect console error